# Checking out from GitHub a specific reference within a Ruby Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems, gemfile

So, I have no Ruby experience at all.  However, I'm being asked to look after some Ruby on Rails / Ruby source code that was left behind by my predecessor.  I'd like to at least get it to install and run within its Docker container.

From what I can tell, it is failing because of the `mimemagic` [problem](https://dev.to/cseeman/what-s-up-with-mimemagic-breaking-everything-he1) from a couple of years ago.  It has a dependency on `mimemagic` v0.3.0 .  I know the right thing to do would be to move on to the recent versions that have not been yanked.  But, with my limited experience with Ruby, I'd like to at least get my predecessor's code to install and run.

Since moving up to the earliest `mimemagic` that is [available](https://rubygems.org/gems/mimemagic/versions/0.3.0) (v0.3.7) appears to break other things, I have been trying to install v0.3.0 using the GitHub reference as a work around.

This:

```
gem 'mimemagic', github: 'mimemagicrb/mimemagic', ref: 'a4b038c6c1b9d76dac33d5711d28aaa9b4c42c66'
```

complains that I'm transmitting without encryption.  It ultimately fails to fetch with a connection time out.

Meanwhile, this:

```
gem 'mimemagic', git: 'git@github.com:mimemagicrb/mimemagic.git', ref: 'a4b038c6c1b9d76dac33d5711d28aaa9b4c42c66'
```

complains that the host key verification has failed.

Finally, this gets me a little further:

```
gem 'mimemagic', git: 'https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic.git', ref: 'a4b038c6c1b9d76dac33d5711d28aaa9b4c42c66'
```

but an error later on looks like this:

```
rake aborted!
Bundler::GitError: The git source https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
```

I have this feeling that "quickly getting it to work" isn't a reality and perhaps all of this will take a lot more than the 1-2 days I've spent so far.  I just would like to check what the correct gem/git commands are, and if any of the above three are close.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you must run the `bundle install` command before starting the application server or accessing the console.

The reference in the Gemfile is added correctly.

```
gem 'mimemagic', git: 'https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic.git', ref: 'a4b038c6c1b9d76dac33d5711d28aaa9b4c42c66'
```

If you've already executed the mentioned command, can you update the question to have the output for this command?

P.S. Read more about the `bundle install` command [here](https://bundler.io/v2.1/man/bundle-install.1.html).